# char printable program

Tags: c++

i have program which prints all char from char_min to  char_max  here is code

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    char c;
    c=CHAR_MIN;
     while(c!=CHAR_MAX){
          printf("d\n",c);
          c=c+1;

     }


return 0;



}
```

but it prints only all d   why?ouput is like  this

```
d
d
d
d
d
d
d
d
d
d
```

...

.
.  press any key to continue

Comment: this is really a good question..... I didn't see it right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
printf("d\n",c);     /// Means just print "d" (c is ignored)
printf("%d\n",c);     /// Means print the decimal value of varaible c
printf("%c\n",c);     /// Means print the charcter value of varaible c
```

Using "%d" will just print "0", "1", "2" etc.

Using "%c" will print the character values: "A", "B", "C" etc.  Note, however, that the first 31 aren't printable.

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
 printf("d\n",c);
```

with

```
printf("%c\n",c);
```

Comment: Have a look at http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output